# Unable to find Dir due to credentials not recognized?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy some files from a local location to a network location accessible only via specific user - So far I have

```
Import-Module bitstransfer
$username = "domain\user"
$password =  Get-Content 'C:\securestring.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist ($username, $password)
$sourcePath = 'C:\folder\file.csv', 'C:\folder\file2.csv'
$destPath = '\\server\share$\', '\\server\share$\'
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Credential $cred
```

I am having issues with authentication, script doesn't seem to be able to pass the parameters through

UPDATE: Appears there is a bug with Bits transfer handling -creds as expected, in order to success one must do net use command to manually establish a connection.

Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

Are these servers in the same domain?

Are the creds the same for both servers?

If this is servers in multiple domains, this may be a Windows double hop Auth issue. See the articles on that topic.

I just did the following in one of my WS2K12 labs and it works as expected, but I have a single forest single domain, and did this only on one server.

```
PS C:\Scripts> Test-Path -Path '\\FileServer01\Data'
True

PS C:\Scripts> Test-Path -Path '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$'
True

PS C:\Scripts> Get-ChildItem -Path '\\FileServer01\Data\*.*'


    Directory: \\FileServer01\Data


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
-a---        11/17/2017   3:57 AM     176640 High_Impact_Data.docx                                                                                                     
-a---        11/17/2017   3:57 AM     184320 Low_Impact_Data.docx                                                                                                      
-a---         2/12/2018   4:00 PM         64 New Text Document.txt                                                                                                     



PS C:\Scripts> Get-ChildItem -Path '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$\'

PS C:\Scripts> Copy-Item -Path '\\FileServer01\Data\*.*' -Destination '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$\'

PS C:\Scripts> Get-ChildItem -Path '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$\'


    Directory: \\FileServer01\TargetShare$


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
-a---        11/17/2017   3:57 AM     176640 High_Impact_Data.docx                                                                                                     
-a---        11/17/2017   3:57 AM     184320 Low_Impact_Data.docx                                                                                                      
-a---         2/12/2018   4:00 PM         64 New Text Document.txt                                                                                                     



PS C:\Scripts> Import-Module -Name BitsTransfer

PS C:\Scripts> Get-ChildItem -Path '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$\'

PS C:\Scripts> Start-BitsTransfer -Source '\\FileServer01\Data\*.*' -Destination '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$\'

PS C:\Scripts> Get-ChildItem -Path '\\FileServer01\TargetShare$\'


    Directory: \\FileServer01\TargetShare$


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
-a---        11/17/2017   3:57 AM     176640 High_Impact_Data.docx                                                                                                     
-a---        11/17/2017   3:57 AM     184320 Low_Impact_Data.docx                                                                                                      
-a---         2/12/2018   4:00 PM         64 New Text Document.txt
```

***Update for OP***

As for this ...

> 'different domain but cred are the same'

Are saying, same forest, with multiple domains or a domain in separate forest?

In either case, are the default bi-directional transitive trusts in place?
(if not, then these are different namespaces and Auth will fail unless you pass two set of creds with the appropriate domain identity)

When you say, the creds are the same, does that mean the account exists in the each domain? That use account can exist in both, but that still means the creds are different, since the domains need to be specified?

So, domain1\postanote is not the same thing as domain2\postanote. Yet, if you were using UPN, domain hints, etc., as the user identity, then it's more flexible than that NetBios one.

This is of course all ADDS requirements, and is a restriction not only on PowerShell, but for any thing requiring Auth.

[How does Authentication Work Cross Domain?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anthonw/2006/08/02/how-does-authentication-work-cross-domain/)

Comment: Yes, destination location is on a server in a different domain but cred are the same, I will look into the articles but I dont see how you've used creds to connect to the server or you did not require authentication to targetshare ?

Comment: The server I used to run these, I am already logged on to he server with creds on the targets, so no need to pass them separately.

Comment: Alright so the dest location is in a separate forest but both locations are on the same server. I believe there is trust in place...i can ping, rdp, navigate to the share with no worries. I noticed when I remove the cred section and run the script once I have navigated to the share and authenticated it works also so It seems to me that i am missing something in order to get the script check and authenticate using the creds then copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

Your destination path should have the filenames mentioned:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source 'C:\folder\file.csv', 'C:\folder\file2.csv' -Destination '\\server\share$\file.csv', '\\server\share$\file2.csv' -Credential $cred
```

Or you need to wrap your variables like this:

```
$destPath = "$('\\server\share$\file.csv', '\\server\share$\file2.csv')"
```

Also if you want the file names to be taken dynamically, then this is perfect scenario to use `foreach` loop and address it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why I need to mention the files names when I have specified them in "$SourcePath". issue i am having is with authentication...script doesnt seem to be registering the auth part.

Comment: @Hex02: Where are the file names in the $destpath? Try copying only one file from the source and mention only the folder in destination not the file name.. You will encounter the error unless you are using wildcard or filename... It expects file name specifically. 
In addition, Authentication might be an issue, which I have not looked into it because I dont know what permission you are having currently

Comment: I have tried already. There is no issue with copying once I have authenticated to the share, read the update I added. Also the user has full perm to the share.